All of my indexed posts only appear in image section
Why are all of my indexed posts only appearing in the image section when searched on Google, but not in the regular search results?
The issue affects my website's ranking, and I'm unsure what the problem could be.
For example: cut him off if he disrespects you.
It appears only in the image section but not in regular search results.
Similarly, all of my 200+ indexed posts have the same problem.
Please help me out of this problem. I invest a big chunk of my time on my website writing blog posts and optimizing for search engines but my posts are not getting any impressions and clicks due to this issue.

I suspect, rightly or wrongly, you're being marked down by the recent low-quality content updates.  This is algorithmic, so I wouldn't take it personally.
If you search for content in quote marks to make it an exact search, eg search "Cut Him Off If He Disrespects You (10 Inspiring Ways)" (including the quotes) then it does appear in the SERPs.
I guess launching a site with that much content might have made it look a bit AI-generated and perhaps triggered their "Scaled content abuse" signals, which is going to be their main reason for being so heavy handed at the moment.
If people start sharing your links on other sites then it should signal to Google that it's worth indexing.

For some reason, I think that's how it is.

No disrespect intended, but if you’ve decided to generate textual content using AI, take some time to dive deeper into the subject.
Focus on keyword density and placement, proper meta tag formatting, publishing consistency, and above all, the quality of your content.
The ideal formula in your case = less fluff — more value.
Also, look into Schema.org microdata to ensure your page content is better understood by search engines.
And don’t forget to check for any indexing errors in Google Search Console that might be affecting your site or its pages.

I’ve Realized that the main issue could be with how my structured data and breadcrumbs are set up, which might be confusing Google. I’ll check those settings and fix any issues. I reviewed my site in Google Search Console, and luckily, there are no penalties or indexing problems.
Thanks for your help! I’m working on these issues and hoping to see better results soon!

Thank you for feedback man!

I checked your website with site:yourwebsite and many of the pages are indexed in Google.
So this can be because of many reasons.
1- Your targeting keywords may be highly competitive and websites ranking against those workers are high authority sites. So your website is not getting clicks and impressions.
2- Another possible reason is that those keywords you are targeting has ZERO search volume. (It happens rarely).
3- If you were getting any clicks and impressions before the August Core Algo update. You need to check your site might be hit by the update. You can confirm this using the Search Console for manual penalties and also use tools to check the drops in traffic.

You’re right, my keywords might be too competitive. I’ve done some research, but I’ll go back and focus on less competitive terms to improve my chances.

That will be the right approach. Start with low-competition keywords, and once those keywords rank well, you can start targeting medium-competition and then high-competition keywords.
